# FFMPEG SCREEN RECORDING: How to get H265 (libx265) recording using ffmpeg with xorg?

Tags: ffmpeg, codec, video-recording, libx265

I really would appreciate all the help I can get here.

I'm trying to use the libx265 codec for recording an xorg dummy screen. The command that currently works for H264 (libx264 codec) is:

> ffmpeg -y -v info -f x11grab -draw_mouse 0 -r 30 -s 1280x720
> -thread_queue_size 4096 -i :0.0+0,0 -f alsa -acodec aac -strict -2 -ar 44100 -b:a 128k -af aresample=async=1 -c:v libx264 -preset fast
> -profile:v main -level 3.1 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30 -crf 21 -g 60 -tune zerolatency -f mp4 capture.mp4

In trying to get H265 instead, I first changed the codec to libx265 like below:

> ffmpeg -y -v info -f x11grab -draw_mouse 0 -r 30 -s 1280x720
> -thread_queue_size 4096 -i :0.0+0,0 -f alsa -acodec aac -strict -2 -ar 44100 -b:a 128k -af aresample=async=1 -c:v libx265 -preset fast
> -profile:v main -level 3.1 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30 -crf 21 -g 60 -tune zerolatency -f mp4 capture.mp4

But that didn't do it. Although it didn't error, it was producing a file that was playing at twice the recorded speed (i.e. twice the speed of the clip that was recorded).

Then I tried using -x265-params to specify the parameters like this:

> ffmpeg -y -v info -f x11grab -draw_mouse 0 -r 30 -s 1280x720
> -thread_queue_size 4096 -i :0.0+0,0 -f alsa -acodec aac -strict -2 -ar 44100 -b:a 128k -af aresample=async=1 -c:v libx264 -preset fast
> -x265-params profile=main:level=3.1:crf=21 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30 -g 60 -tune zerolatency -f mp4 capture.mp4

And this gave me an error with the following message:

**"output file #0 does not contain any stream ffmpeg"**

I've tried all sorts of combinations, searched extensively online (for both how to set 265 parameters and on the output file error), but I'm not making a headway. I'm really new to all this. Can anyone please help (with the most simple terms and directions)?

Comment: What's the `-strict -2` for? You are not declaring an input  (`-i`) for alsa. What are you playing the output video with?

Comment: @llogan the strict flag is to force conformity to all the things in the spec no matter what consequences. The full code run in in xorg to capture a chrome screen has plug:bsnoop for alsa, but I took that out when running on ffmpeg command line because it produces an error outside the chrome instance.